# Memory leak in Weblogic 10.3.2

Tags: weblogic

Has anyone encountered a memory leak in Weblogic 10.3.2 on Solaris 9? I've recently upgraded from Weblogic 9.2MP1 and a slow memory leak occurs.

Cheers,
Darrel

Comment: I face strange weblogic (v10.3.3) behavior on Ubuntu: http://serverfault.com/questions/260395/weblogic-administration-console-way-too-slow

Comment: If it is possible (no EJBs). Just deploy application to a simple web container and monitor it. To consider the memory leak introduced by application.